# Laravel 5.6 Monolog to output in Chrome console

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6, monolog, chromephp

I recently switched from Laravel 5.5 to 5.6

Everything's working fine except I can't seem to get logging to the Chrome console to work.

I used to do this in AppServiceProvider.php

```
$monolog            = Log::getMonolog();

if (config('app.env') === 'local') {
    $infohandler = new ChromePHPHandler(Logger::INFO, false);
    $infohandler->setFormatter(new ChromePHPFormatter());
    $monolog->pushHandler($infohandler);
}
```

The 'getMonolog' seems to have been removed. Anyone have quick solution to get this working again?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to have been changed to `Log::getLogger()` which makes sense, it doesn't necessarily have to be Monolog anymore.

https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Log/Logger.html#method_getLogger

Comment: That was quick indeed! Thanx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

in 5.6 if you're customising monolog you need to create a custom logging channel

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/logging#creating-custom-channels